Integral $ \int_{3\pi \over 4}^{\pi \over 4}\pi(-1 + \sqrt{2}\sin t)^2\sqrt{2}(-\sin t) dt $
The integral
$$
I = \int_{3\pi \over 4}^{\pi \over 4}\pi(-1 + \sqrt{2}\sin t)^2\sqrt{2}(-\sin t) dt
$$
represents the volume of the revolution around $x$-axis of the curve
$$
\begin{cases}
x=1+\sqrt{2}\cos t, \\
y=-1 + \sqrt{2}\sin t
\end{cases},
t \in [{\pi \over 4}, {3\pi \over 4}]
$$
My attempt :
Open the square $(-1 + \sqrt{2}\sin t)^2$ and then compute each part.
That process is painful and cumbersome.
The result is never correct due to mistakes.
So I'm wondering if there are some tricks to make the integration easier?
(Correct answer is $I = 2\pi\left({5 \over 3} - {\pi \over 2}\right)$ according to the text)

You can shift the curve to the left maybe.

Integral by part maybe easier than "open the square and compute each part". See my methond two. But also need some computation!

$$I=\sqrt2\pi\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\sin t(\sqrt{2}\sin t-1)^2 dt\\
=\sqrt2\pi\left[2\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\sin^3tdt
-2\sqrt2\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\sin^2tdt
+\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\sin t dt\right].$$
Let
$$I_1=\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\sin^3tdt,\quad I_2=\sqrt2\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\sin^2tdt,\quad I_3=\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\sin t dt,$$
then
$$I_1=\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}(\cos^2t-1)d(\cos t)
=\left(\frac{\cos^3t}{3}-\cos t\right)\bigg|^{3\pi/4}_{\pi/4}
=\frac{5}{3 \sqrt{2}};$$
$$I_2=\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}
=\left(\frac{t}2-\frac{\sin(2t)}{4}\right)\bigg|^{3\pi/4}_{\pi/4}
=\frac{\pi + 2}{4};$$
$$I_3=\cos t\bigg|_{3\pi/4}^{\pi/4}=\sqrt2.$$
So
$$I=\sqrt2\pi\left[2\cdot\frac{5}{3 \sqrt{2}}-2\sqrt2\cdot\frac{\pi + 2}{4}
+\sqrt2\right]
= \pi\left({10\over 3}-\pi\right).$$
Add:  By symmetry, we have
$$I=2\sqrt2\pi\left[2\int^{\pi\over2}_{\pi\over4}\sin^3tdt
-2\sqrt2\int^{\pi\over2}_{\pi\over4}\sin^2tdt
+\int^{\pi\over2}_{\pi\over4}\sin t dt\right],$$
maybe easier!
Metohd two: Integral by part:
$$I=-\sqrt2\pi\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}(\sqrt{2}\sin t-1)^2 d(\cos t)\\
=-\sqrt2\pi\left[\cos t(\sqrt{2}\sin t-1)^2\bigg|^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}
-2\sqrt2\cdot\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\cos^2t(\sqrt2\sin t-1)dt\right]\\
=4\pi\cdot\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\cos^2t(\sqrt2\sin t-1)dt\\
=4\pi\left[\sqrt2\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\cos^2t\sin tdt
-\int^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\cos^2tdt\right]\\
=4\pi\left[\frac{\sqrt2}3\cos^3t\bigg|_{3\pi\over4}^{\pi\over4}-\left(\frac{t}2+\frac{\sin(2t)}{4}\right)^{3\pi\over4}_{\pi\over4}\right]
=\pi\left({10\over 3}-\pi\right).$$

+1 nice answer. Technically, this is exactly what the op wanted to avoid "open the square and compute each part"

@whatamidoing
Yes, but I find it is not to bad when I "open the square and compute each part" .Also I try some other mentohdds, all are not so easier than this direct method!

So it's a skill issue LOL. Perhaps the problem creator intended for me to master integrals over $\sin x, \sin^2 x, \sin^3 x$, as the integral conveniently breaks down into integrating them separately.

So I found that I've always been computing volume or area of solid of revolution without the parameter $t$, i.e, the relation of $y$ and $x$ is directly given usually. By realizing the curve actually represents a circle centered at $(1, -1)$ with radius $r=\sqrt{2}$, and $t \in [{\pi \over 4}, {3\pi \over 4}]$ selects the part above x-axis, the curve can be rewritten as:
$$
(x-1)^2 + (y+1)^2=2, x: 0 \to 2
$$
The integral can therefore be rewritten to
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\pi\int_{0}^{2}\left(\sqrt{2-(x-1)^2}-1\right)^2dx\\&=\pi\int_{0}^{2}\left(2-x^2+2x-2\sqrt{2-(x-1)^2}\right)dx \\
&=\pi\left[\left(2x-{1\over 3}x^3+x^2\right)\vert_{0}^{2}-2\int_{-{\pi \over 4}}^{\pi \over 4}\sqrt{2 - 2\sin^2 t}\sqrt{2}\cos t dt\right]\\
&= \pi \left(8-{8 \over 3}-8\int_{0}^{\pi \over 4}\cos^2 t dt\right) \\
&= \pi \left(8-{8 \over 3}-\pi-2\right) \\
&= \pi \left({10 \over 3} - \pi\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Trig integrals always make me headache, and polynomial is easier, so I hope this will provide another perspective.
